# My draft inducer fan slows down and then shuts off after ignition

Tags: furnace

I just replaced the draft inducer motor/fan. the old one was screeching and difficult to spin.

After replacing the part, the draft inducer starts, and the ignition occurs, but before the blower motor comes on, burners turn off and back on but not all the way on. The draft inducer seems to either be told to stop or is having issues running. It slows down (it is not variable speed) and it continues to try to run for 1-2 minutes until finally the entire system turns off and flashes a code for a soft lockout (max trials for ignition reached)

When the draft inducer first experienced problems it seemed as though it was experiencing a suction blockage, but I can't find any blockage. It also sounds as if there is paper in the inducer fan. I have taken it apart several times and there is no water and no debris.

I would also note that when I install the inducer motor, it is easy to spin by hand, but every time it runs and turns off, it is very difficult to turn until I remove it from the furnace at which point it spins freely again.
Please help!

Comment: "trails" >> "trials" (attempts)?

Comment: Sounds like the inducer is either being deformed by installation or pressed against something that shouldn't be there. Does it sit in place without pressure?

Comment: If the inducer bracket has four attachment points, then one could be out of plane with the others Put it in with just three screws and see if it runs.

Comment: Without knowing the furnace model and the schematic of the control board we can only guess, **so here is my guess, there is still power on the motor that keeps it from turning by hand**

Answer (score 2):

So far so good. The draft inducer start as it should. But then it gets a report from an air pressure switch, that measures the amount of air that’s being blown by the draft inducer.

If the pressure switch reports that there is an inadequate amount of air blowing through the heat exchanger, it will shut down your system. Check for free air flow and the function of the air pressure switch.

> but every time it runs and turns off, it is very difficult to turn until I remove it from the furnace at which point it spins freely again

Could indicate there is still power on the motor preventing you from turning it by hand. In that case try disconnecting the power cable from the inducer to remove all power.